# Burninate [pc] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

This tag, [pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pc), seems absolutely pointless, has no tag wiki or anything.  It's just vague, and can mean several things.

Comment: Agree it's mostly very vague. 286 questions to be sorted though. And some currently might make it useful, which would need a better alternative:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168675/android-control-function-on-pc-with-cell

Comment: @James "Windows" is probably more appropriate for that question.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg downvoting and closing as "too broad" is probably most appropriate for that question. It should be deleted, regardless of tags.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg really? I use Linux.. My mate uses a Mac..

Comment: @l4mpi I was referring only to the tag usage.  Yes, it should be closed.

Comment: @James Let's say that you were asking that question and that it was otherwise on-topic.  Let's say that you wanted to communicate with a Linux machine.  Should the tag be "pc"?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: A pc can run Linux as well as Windows and countless other OSes, which was the point.

Comment: @Deduplicator Do you suppose that someone wants to communicate at the hardware level, or with the OS?  Why would someone ask a question about a "PC" without specifying the operating system?

Comment: The point perhaps being missed by some commenters here is that in common usage among the semi-tech-literate, *a PC* can mean "a personal computer", "a Windows computer", or "a non-Apple computer". I don't know whether there's any strong reason to consider any of these usages 'correct' and the others wrong, nor do I especially care - the only meaning that's useful as a tag on SO is 'a Windows computer' and that can - as pointed out by @MatthewLundberg - be indicated via the 'windows' tag instead and with less chance of ambiguity.

Comment: My first thought was _program counter_, for what it's worth, though [pc] doesn't seem to be used in that sense.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg That particular question I linked to really requires 2 X `Device` and 2 X `Operating System` tags (although ideally just two tags in total with `[device-os]`). Other questions would be fine with or without `PC`. e.g. "How can I develop Android apps on my Windows Laptop". (that other question sucks anyway, but that's another matter..)

Comment: Did you know there's a [tag:question] tag? ;)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski [no, actually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/omg_no_there_actually_isnt). It has 0 questions and no tag wiki, thus it does not exist.

Comment: @l4mpi Go to the tags tab and type *question* in the search box. Guess what shows up in the results ;)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski That is because [question] is a synonym of [questions] which does not exist (blacklisted?).

Comment: @Jason You're right, the tag does not appear in the autocompletion list when asking a new question (fortunately).

Comment: *political correct* tagging