# The [pc] tag description is not very PC

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, tag-wiki

There is a [two year old burninate request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274463/burninate-pc-tag), but it seems the only outcome was to add this rather questionable tag description to [pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pc):

> Anything about personal computers.

A quick look shows that yes, most of the questions are anything about PCs and are heavily voted down. At a bare minimum, the tag text should be reworded to some sort of **DO NOT USE!**-type message, I would suggest.

I'm not too confident about the exact wording to use, so that's why I'm posting rather than doing it myself.

Comment: This, or we must add `pc` to all questions that are *not* specifically about high end supercomputers :P

Comment: @RadLexus or embedded hardware? can hardly call that a "pc" right? :P

Comment: Is there a consensus we can burninate this now?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Considering the [criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) defined:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It doesn't usually describe anything in the question. Most of the things here are related to PCs and the definition of PC is not unambiguous.

2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Programming for PCs is very much on-topic, but PCs themselves aren't.

3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Not really, since most questions are about programming for PCs.

4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

It kinda does and doesn't.

Based on this I would totally agree that the tag should be burninated.

Comment: I would add that professionnaly when we talk about applications that are made to run on PC, as the opposite of mobile, we use the term [tag:desktop], for others things not related to applications, it can be [tag:hardware] and others way more meaningfull tags.

Comment: @Walfrat agreed about the desktop tag being the counterpart of the mobile tag, but a mobile device is far more of a personal computer than a desktop computer ever will be ;) This tag just needs to go.

Comment: @Gimby I guess we can be pedantic about it, but if you say "a PC", most people will think about laptop/desktops, not mobiles, even in the developer world.

Comment: @Walfrat where that leaves tablets, phablets and the like?

Comment: @Braiam i'm not putting the right definition of what is a "personal computer", i'm just saying if you go to some random people and talk about "PC" they won't think of mobiles, tablets and so on. That doesn't mean they're right.

Comment: @Walfrat To your point, there's a good chance a "random person" would be even _more_ narrow in their definition and only consider a machine running Windows to be a "PC". As wrong-headed as that may be, the term "PC" conjures up visions of John Hodgeman in a brown suit for a rather large number of people.

Comment: @jmbpiano well yeah but in fact I think I have a bit exagerated or be unclear, Yes they will see a Windows PC in their mind if you talk about a PC. but if you show them a Linux desktop or laptop they'll still consider it's a PC, but not a mobile or a tablette, because they don't see in it the same usage and thus not the same thing.

Comment: This discussion belongs on the meta meta.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK, the only useful technical meaning of PC is [PC-AT compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PC_compatible).

I.e. a system with an x86 CPU and a boot ROM that behaves in a certain way (loading the boot sector to a specific address and so on), and a bunch of system hardware (like the PIC) at standard I/O addresses.

Any question about any of these things can be adequately tagged with just `[x86]`, and current questions about x86 booloaders / osdev / hardware don't use the `[pc]` tag.

**Since the tag doesn't get used in the one case where it has a somewhat-clear specific technical meaning, it's useless.**  And more importantly, it's hard to imagine any good uses for it *other* than that, as the question and Sami's answer point out.

The `[x86]` tag is low-traffic enough that there's no need for any tag for PC-specific x86 questions.