# Priority Clean the [pc]!

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

<sub>I know this has been asked [before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274463/5211833), but as that post is 6 years old and doesn't offer arguments, I decided to repost, rather than edit.</sub>

Apparently there is [pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pc), with the wonderfully descriptive wiki excerpt:

> Anything about personal computers.

and an equally enlightening wiki itself:

> PC is an abbreviation for personal computers. Use the PC tag for any support needed for any computer.

Clearly Stack Overflow isn't for "Anything about personal computers" ('Can I boil eggs on my power supply?' springs to mind), or for "any support needed for any computer" ('The on-board computer in my new car burned out, could you fix it please?').

Having established this, here are the four burnination categories:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No.

2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

No.

3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No.

4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No.

The reason for most "No" answers here is the "any" part of the tag wiki.

Can we please burninate it?

Comment: Post it as an answer over there instead.